# How exactly work the JPA\Hibernate OneToMany annotation?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0

I am studying for the Spring Core certification and i am finding some douts about how to use JPA\Hibernate in an exercise.

So I have 2 DB tables named respectivelly **T_ACCOUNT** and **T_ACCOUNT_BENEFICIARY**.

These tables have the following structure:

```
create table T_ACCOUNT (ID integer identity primary key, NUMBER varchar(9), NAME varchar(50) not null, CREDIT_CARD varchar(16), unique(NUMBER));

create table T_ACCOUNT_BENEFICIARY (ID integer identity primary key, ACCOUNT_ID integer, NAME varchar(50), ALLOCATION_PERCENTAGE decimal(5,2) not null, SAVINGS decimal(8,2) not null, unique(ACCOUNT_ID, NAME));
```

And the **T_ACCOUNT** table is bound to the **T_ACCOUNT_BENEFICIARY** table with a **one to many** relation, this is the graphical representation:

[image]

And this is code of the **Account** class that map the **T_ACCOUNT** table:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="T_ACCOUNT")
public class Account {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="id")
    private Long entityId;

    @Column(name="NUMBER")
    private String number;

    @Column(name="NAME")
    private String name;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name="ACCOUNT_ID")
    private Set<Beneficiary> beneficiaries = new HashSet<Beneficiary>();

    @Column(name="CREDIT_CARD")
    private String creditCardNumber;

    // GETTERS & SETTERS
}
```

So my doubt is related about this field mapping that handle the **one to many** relation between the **T_ACCOUNT** and the **T_ACCOUNT_BENEFICIARY** tables:

```
@OneToMany
@JoinColumn(name="ACCOUNT_ID")
private Set<Beneficiary> beneficiaries = new HashSet<Beneficiary>();
```

I know that, on the DB, this relationship is implemented by the **ACCOUNT_ID** field of the **T_ACCOUNT_BENEFICIARY** table (so multiple row of the **T_ACCOUNT_BENEFICIARY** table can have the same value of the **ACCOUNT_ID** field and this means that a single row of the **T_ACCOUNT** table can be associated to more than one rows of **T_ACCOUNT_BENEFICIARY** table).

My doubt is: in this field mapping I am not using the **@Column** annotation because the Beneficiary objects (that represents single rows of **T_ACCOUNT_BENEFICIARY** table) are not represented as field (column) of my **T_ACCOUNT** table. So instead it is used **@JoinColumn(name="ACCOUNT_ID")**.

But how JPA\Hibernated know what is the right table? I think that it have to automatically  look how is annotated the **Beneficiary** class.

Is it the right interpretation related to how it works?

Tnx

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track. The next thing you need to do is to annotate your Beneficiary class with `@Entity` and `@Table` annotations. And then hibernate will understand what you are trying to do. You have not posted your Beneficiary class so I believe it's a unidirectional relationship (i.e. Beneficiary does not have @ManyToOne annotation). In case you want to specify bidirectional relationship in your domain model you would need to put `@ManyToOne` annotation with `mappedBy` in your Beneficiary class like below.

```
@Entity
@Table("T_ACCOUNT_BENEFICIARY")
public class Beneficiary {
 @ManyToOne(mappedBy = "beneficiaries")
 Account account;
 ...
}
```